# center image that is bigger than the containing div

Tags: css, image, center

this is what I have:

```
.thumbnail {
    height: 600px;
    width: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail img {
    height: 600px;
     width: auto;
}
```

the width of the image can be any size, maybe larger then the container div. how can I center it?

Comment: easy option is to use it as a background for the div. and then `background-position-x : center`

Comment: You could always use flexbox? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oOQarq

Comment: can you provide your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Flex for simple, as your question, assume image free size (No CSS set)

```
.thumbnail {
    height: 600px;
    width: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.thumbnail {
    height: 600px;
    width: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px;">
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this

```
.thumbnail img {
    height: 600px;
     width: auto;
     display:block;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: can you provide your Html